# Joining multiple tables to a bridge table while keeping both sides of data (Including NULLs)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, mapping

I have the following table scenario:

Table A:

```
ID | Value
1    Apple
2    Orange
3    Banana
```

Table B:

```
ID | Value
6    Sorbet
7    Ice Cream
```

Table C (Bridge/Mapping Table):

```
A_ID | B_ID
1      7
```

I want to join these tables such that I get all of the data from both tables A and B, but also show that a mapping exists between the rows if it does.  The ideal solution table would look like this:

```
A_ID | A_Value | Mapped? | B_ID | B_Value
1      Apple     Yes       7      Ice Cream
2      Orange    No        NULL   NULL
3      Banana    No        NULL   NULL
NULL   NULL      No        6      Sorbet
```

I have tried many ways so far using LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, but I cannot get a join structure to work where it includes data on both sides of the bridge no matter what.

This query was what I was thinking could work but it still removed many rows that were not mapped from my result:

```
select a.A_ID, a.Value, b.B_ID, b.Value
from
(Select * from TableA left join TableC on TableA.ID = TableC.A_ID) a
JOIN
(Select * from TableB left join TableC on TableB.ID = TableC.B_ID) b
on a.A_ID = b.A_ID and a.B_ID = b.B_ID
```

Comment: take a look at FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: Full outer join seems to be the solution I was looking for.  Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll mark it, thanks!

Comment: Great . I won't be able to reply todau. If someone else's answer solves it then feel free to accept their answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a mix of `LEFT JOIN` and a `FULL OUTER JOIN` the desired output can be reached:

```
SELECT  A.ID AS A_ID,
        A.Value AS A_Value,
        CASE WHEN C.A_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
        END AS Mapped,
        B.ID AS B_ID,
        B.Value AS B_Value
FROM    @TableA A
LEFT JOIN @TableC C ON C.A_ID = A.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN @TableB B ON B.ID = C.B_ID;
```

[Working example](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/51242db9a108c6ac7ae446a0d88e76e6)

```
A_ID    A_Value Mapped  B_ID    B_Value
1       Apple   Yes     7       Ice Cream
2       Orange  No      NULL    NULL
3       Banana  No      NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    No      6       Sorbet
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 full outer joins:

```
   select 
        a.ID as A_ID, 
        a.Value as A_Value, 
        case when 
            (a.id=c.a_id and c.b_id=b.id) 
                then 'yes' 
                else 'no' 
        END as Mapped ,
        b.ID as B_ID, 
        b.Value as B_value
    from tableA a full outer join tableC c on a.id=c.a_id
    full outer join tableB b on c.b_id=b.id
```

and the result is

```
A_ID        A_Value Mapped B_ID        B_value
----------- ------- ------ ----------- ---------
1           Apple   yes    7           Ice Cream
2           Orange  no     NULL        NULL
3           Banana  no     NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL    no     6           Sorbet
```